# Need help displaying a set dynamic date and time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I want my website to display my local time and date for everyone to see.

Let's say it is currently `6:25 PM on December 17, 2014` in my time zone and a visitor to the site's time and date is at the same time `2:25 PM on December 18, 2014`. What I am basically trying to do is have my website display in that instance `12/17/14 6:25:?? PM` with `??` being the seconds but the time and date must be dynamic and update on its own by the second.

I would very much appreciate some help in being able to get this done and I hope I have been specific enough this time but if I haven't please let me know how I can be so this doesn't get blocked again.

Comment: show your efforts... I will help you from that onwards!

Comment: I would if I could but this site always stops me and says the coding isn't displayed right because of all the spaces and stuff. I used places like dynamicdrive and w3schools as resources though.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, your question is a bit vague. You just want a clock with date to be shown on your webpage? Unless you provide some code, I can't add it to your existing project, but I made a working code in HTML. With some inspiration from W3School (http://www.w3schools.com) I ended up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function startTime() {
                var today=new Date();
                var day = today.getDate();
                var month = today.getMonth();
                var year = today.getFullYear();
                var h=today.getHours();
                var m=today.getMinutes();
                var s=today.getSeconds();
                m = checkTime(m);
                s = checkTime(s);
                document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Date: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + "Clock: " + h+":"+m+":"+s;
                var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
            }

            function checkTime(i) {
                if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
                return i;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startTime()">

        <div id="txt"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Is this what you mean?

The edit is just that I made variables of the date too.

Comment: It is like that yes but I need it to display a set date and time based on a single time zone rather than the visitor's local time. In other words I want everyone to see the same dynamic time and date no matter where they visit from be it China or Europe or America.

Comment: Since no one has answered during vacation, I can rip it up again! There exists several libraries out there, for instance momentjs.com. These libraries provides the opportunity to set timezones, formatting etc. Take a look at the docs here: [link](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/)