# How to get nth Weekday of Current date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to retrieve nth weekday of the current date in js. like 1st Sunday, 2nd Sunday

var d=new Date();
var weekDay=d.getDay();

here weekDay gives me 4 that means its Wednesday(3rd Wednesday). So far its good.

from weekDay i can say that its wednesday.

how to calcuate the "3rd" index of this wednesday?

Thank you

Comment: Don't be rude. Show us some love and add your attempted code to question?

Comment: Before? After? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry guys if i am rude, i did this kind of this in c# and sql server and i have no idea in javascript. This is my first question here.

Comment: So do you mean 2nd sunday of the month ?

Comment: The question is not clear enough

Comment: yes adeneo. eg:1/16/2015 is 3rd Friday

Comment: amy, i think the question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

What du you actually mean? To get the dates you could use Date(). Like for instance creating a variable "today" and setting it to be todays date.

```
var today = new Date();
```

In a greater context you could go as far as showing everything from weekdays, date, year etc etc! I'll provide a code bit below. The code shows a dynamic clock/date in HTML.

You can format this the way you want, and choose which variables to show! This is btw the same code as found here: [Other thread/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481526/need-help-displaying-a-set-dynamic-date-and-time/27481970#27481970)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function startTime() {
                var today=new Date();
                var day = today.getDate();
                var month = today.getMonth();
                var year = today.getFullYear();
                var h=today.getHours();
                var m=today.getMinutes();
                var s=today.getSeconds();
                m = checkTime(m);
                s = checkTime(s);
                document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Date: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + "Clock: " + h+":"+m+":"+s;
                var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
            }

            function checkTime(i) {
                if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
                return i;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startTime()">

        <div id="txt"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
    function getNth(dat) {
        var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday','saturday'],
            nth  = ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th'],
            d    = dat ? dat instanceof Date ? dat : new Date(dat) : new Date(),
            date = d.getDate(),
            day  = d.getDay(),
            n    = Math.ceil(date / 7);
        
        return n + nth[n-1] + ' ' + days[day];
    }


    document.body.innerHTML = '' +
        'today ....: ' + getNth() + '<br>' +
        '1/31/2015 : ' + getNth('1/31/2015') + '<br>' +
        '1/16/2015 : ' + getNth('1/16/2015');
```

```css
body {font-family: monospace}
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo. it works but i can get that for 1/31/2015. it says NAN Saturday

Comment: @VittyVardhan - didn't think about the fifth, only added four "nth" in the array, fixed now !

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want what date will be 1st, 2nd sunday/Monday from today. If it is that then you can use this

```
//consider sun=o,mon=1,....,sat:6

function getWeekday(n,day)
{
    var today = new Date();
    var presentDay = today.getDay();
    var presentTime = today.getTime();
    if(day < presentDay)
    {
        day = day +6;
    }

    var diff = day - present day;

    var daysAfter = (n-1)*7 + diff;

    var timeAfter = presentTime+daysAfter*86400000;

    var next date = new Date(timeAfter);
}

// if you want to get 1st sunday from today just call this
   var sunday1 = getWeekday(1,0)

// to get second monday from today 
   var monday2 = getWeekday(2,1)
```